# Edit xml file with C++/CLI

Tags: .net, xml, c++-cli, edit

I'm using `using namespace System::Xml;` and I want easily edit xml files (e.g. write a new value for existing tag `<test>`)

Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>  
  <test>VALUE</test>
</note>
```

How can I do this? (with XmlTextWriter and XmlTextReader?)

Thx

Comment: Do you know how to do it in C# or another pure managed language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// open XML file
System::Xml::XmlDocument xmlDoc;
xmlDoc.Load("Test.xml");

// find desired node
XmlNode ^node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//test");

if (node != null)
{
    node->InnerText = "NEWVALUE"; // write new value 
}
else // if the node is not present in the xml file
{
    XmlNode ^root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    XmlElement ^elem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("key");
    elem->InnerText = "NEWVALUE";
    root->AppendChild(elem);
}

// if you want to write the whole xml file to a System::String
StringWriter ^stringWriter = gcnew StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter ^xmlWriter = gcnew XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);  

System::String ^str = stringWriter->ToString();

xmlDoc.Save("Test.xml"); // finally save the changes to xml file
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, you insisted on using  XmlTextWriter and XmlTextReader.

Comment: You see the "?" after XmlTextWriter and XmlTextReader?! It was only an idea how it could work!

Answer (score 1):

```
System::Xml::Linq::XDocument^ doc = System::Xml::Linq::XDocument::Load("q.xml");
doc->Root->Element("test")->Value = "zz"; 
doc->Save("q.xml");
```

with reference on System.Xml.Linq